# Creation of new project fails with "access denied"

Tags: netbeans, codenameone

The creation fails at this stage:

[image]

The user has admin rights on her laptop. Thoughts?

Comment: What version of NetBeans are you using?

Comment: This is NetBeans version 8.2

Comment: What were the settings in the previous page of the wizard? Check out the netbeans log file it might have additional details there. Windows is sometimes very finicky about working with open files so if she has the project directory open somewhere or has something running on it (even Anti-virus) that can be a problem. These things can also happen because of JDK 9 which we don't support yet as it broke too many things.

Comment: will ask about these possiblities thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason could be the location of the project on the device. Windows 8/8.1/10 prevents access to many of the the directories in `C:` (or the drive where it is installed).

Try running netbeans as an admin or changing the location of the project.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit was the anti virus. Thanks to Shai for the pointer.

Comment: I accept the answer by @Aditya because it seems to be a more frequent cause of error.